# Stdin + Dictionary Text Replacement Tool -- Debugging

Tags: c, string, dictionary, binary, stdin

I'm working on a project in which I have two main files. Essentially, the program reads in a text file defining a dictionary with key-value mappings. Each key has a unique value and the file is formatted like this where each key-value pair is on its own line:

```
ipsum i%#@!
fubar fubar
IpSum XXXXX24
Ipsum YYYYY211
```

Then the program reads in input from stdin, and if any of the "words" match the keys in the dictionary file, they get replaced with the value. There is a slight thing about upper and lower cases -- this is the order of "match priority"

1. The exact word is in the replacement set
2. The word with all but the first character converted to lower case is in the replacement set
3. The word converted completely to lower case is in the replacement set

Meaning if the exact word is in the dictionary, it gets replaced, but if not the next possibility (2) is checked and so on...

My program passes the basic cases we were provided but then the terminal shows
that the output vs reference binary files differ.

I went into both files (not c files, but binary files), and one was super long with tons of numbers and the other just had a line of random characters.  So that didn't really help. I also reviewed my code and made some small tests but it seems okay? A friend recommended I make sure I'm accounting for the null operator in processInput() and I already was (or at least I think so, correct me if I'm wrong). I also converted getchar() to an int to properly check for EOF, and allocated extra space for the char array. I also tried `vimdiff` and got more confused. I would love some help debugging this, please! I've been at it all day and I'm very confused.

Comment: sorry! I didnt know that was required. Originally I had worried it would be super long and confusing if I put it all in there. In any case, its up now! Thank you for letting me know

Comment: You have functions. You could test them.

Comment: There's a problem in the `stringEquals` function (but not the problem you're looking for). Equal hash values isn't the same as equal strings. For example, the strings `"Bb"` and `"CA"` have the same hash value. I think you're just supposed to cast the `void` pointers to `char` pointers, and then use `strcmp` to check if the strings are equal.

Comment: @user3386109 thank you! i fixed that. any ideas what the problem im looking for is?

Comment: @wildplasser im trying to

Comment: `if(ind >= cap) {` -->> `if(ind+1 >= cap) {`  :: reserve place for the NUL byte, too! (and you are also missing the last word before EOF)

Comment: `} else {
        word[ind] = '\0'; 
        char key[ind + 1]; 
        strcpy(key, word);
        checkData(key, ind); ` -->> `} else {
        if (ind) {word[ind] = '\0'; 
        char key[ind + 1]; 
        strcpy(key, word);
        checkData(key, ind); }` <<-- dont process empty tokens.

Comment: `void checkData(char *key, int capacity) {
  char *data = findData(dictionary, key); 
  char copy[capacity];` -->> `void checkData(char *key, int capacity) {
  char *data = findData(dictionary, key); 
  char copy[capacity+1];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the `processInput()` function:

- the loop should not stop when the byte read is 0, you should process the full input with:

  ```
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
  ```
- the test for `EOF` should actually be done differently so the last word of the file gets a chance to be handled if it occurs exactly at the end of the file.
- the cast in `isalnum((char)ch)` is incorrect: you should pass `ch` directly to `isalnum`. Casting as `char` is actually counterproductive because it will turn byte values beyond `CHAR_MAX` to negative values for which `isalnum()` has undefined behavior.
- the test `if(ind >= cap)` is too loose: if `word` contains `cap` characters, setting the null terminator at `word[ind]` will write beyond the end of the array. Change the test to `if (cap - ind < 2)` to allow for a byte and a null terminator at all times.
- you should check that there is at least one character in the word to avoid calling `checkData()` with an empty string.
- `char key[ind + 1];` is useless: you can just pass `word` to `checkData()`.
- `checkData(key, ind)` is incorrect: you should pass the size of the buffer for the case conversions, which is at least `ind + 1` to allow for the null terminator.
- the cast in `putchar((char)ch);` is useless and confusing.

There are some small issues in the rest of the code, but none that should cause a problem.

Comment: ohhh I believe the first suggestion fixed it! thanks so much! I have a few follow up questions -- how would you recommend I deal with the edge case in which the input file does not end on a new line? Im running a test I made which has two lines of text (lorem on line 1, IPSUM on line 2, no new line at the end) but my program only outputs one line (lorem, which is not in the dictionary). I tried to add another if statement which checks if ch=='\n' and then output it, but Im still having issues

Comment: also, how do you typically know to add 1 (for example for checkData)? If the array starts from the zero index, shouldnt ind be enough?

Comment: @Manaal: I fixed the code for `processInput()` to handle the edge case of a word at the end of the file. Testing for `EOF` occurs after processing the word, if any.  And in case anyone wonders, `isalnum(EOF)` is specified as returning 0.

Comment: @Manaal: the local array `copy` in function `checkData` must have a size of `strlen(key) + 1` because of the null terminator. Changing the case does not change the string length (this would not be true for UTF-8 encoded strings, but here you only deal with single byte characters sets).

Comment: thanks again! btw I deleted my code in the original post to prevent possibly other students in my class from seeing it. id really appreciate it if you could abridge your answer/code too! :))

Comment: @Manaal: why should they not benefit from my help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat so we dont spam the comments haha] (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228394/discussion-between-manaal-and-chqrlie).

Answer (score 0):

Start by testing your tokeniser with:

```
$ ./a.out <badhash2.c >zooi
$ diff badhash2.c zooi
$
```

Does it work for binary files, too?:

```
$ ./a.out <./a.out > zooibin
$ diff ./a.out zooibin
$
```

Yes, it does!

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void processInput(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  processInput();
  return 0;
}

void processInput() {
  int ch;
  char *word;
  int len = 0;
  int cap = 60;
  word = malloc(cap);

  while(1) {
    ch = getchar();                 // (1)
    if( ch != EOF && isalnum(ch)) { // (2)
        if(len+1 >= cap) {          // (3)
            cap += cap/2;
            word = realloc(word, cap);
        }
        word[len++] = ch;
    } else {
        if (len) {                  // (4)
#if 0
            char key[len + 1]; 
            memcpy(key, word, len); key[len] = 0; 
            checkData(key, len); 
#else
            word[len] = 0;
            fputs(word, stdout); 
#endif
            len = 0; 
            }
        if (ch == EOF) break;      // (5)
        putchar(ch); 
      }
    }
    free(word);

  }
```

---

I only repaired your tokeniser, leaving out the hash table and the search & replace stuff. It is now supposed to generate a verbatim copy of the input. (which is silly, but great for testing)

1. If you want to allow binary input, you cannot use `while((ch = getchar()) ...)` : a NUL in the input would cause the loop to end. You must pospone testing for EOF, because ther could still be a final word in your buffer `...&& ch != EOF)`
2. treat EOF just like a space here: it could be the end of a word
3. you must reserve space for the NUL ('\0') , too.
4. if (len==0) there would be no word, so no need to look it up.
5. we treated EOF just like a space, but we don't want to write it to the output. Time to break out of the loop.

Comment: when testing the tokenizer how would I input four arguments -- both the input (say its input.txt), the dictionary (dict.txt), the reference output (corrOut.txt) and the actual output (output.txt)?

Comment: also, when i added in the if(ind) you recommended, both the tests failed :(

Comment: a few more questions -- why do we need to hashtag if statements, and why is the first if 0? isnt 0 always false, which means that section wouldnt execute?

Comment: im also confused about why we moved the while (ch!= EOF) condition into the if statement, if we have an if statement that checks the very same at the end and breaks if need be?

Comment: `hashtag if statements` ( you meant: `#if 0 `) is a way to conditionally *comment out* code.